# JSON result is being duplicated in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to write the result that is being returned by JSON to a TXT file. The issue I am facing is that each time the result is returned with each iteration in the array, it takes all the array numbers, for example, the first iteration is taking the first number in the array `$array_1`, the second iteration is taking the first and the second number.

Code as below:

```
<?php
$array_1 = array(4901,2507,2644);
$array_length = count($array_1);
$iterator=0;
while($iterator < $array_length)
{

$record_id = $array_1[$iterator];
$url = "https://example.com" . $record_id;
$curl = curl($url);
$json = fetch_value($curl, '<script type="application/ld+json">', '</script>');
$movie_id = fetch_value($curl, 'id="page_id" value="', '">');
$name = fetch_value($curl, '"name":"', '",');
.
.
.
 $movie_info[] = array(
                "0" => $movie_id,
                "1" => $name,
);

$result = array("result" => $movie_info);
$data = json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$data = PHP_EOL . $data;
$myfile = file_put_contents('final.txt', $data.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

$iterator++;
}
?>
```

The result returned is

**Final.txt result:**

```
{"result":[["4901","movie #1"]]}
{"result":[["4901","movie #1",],["2507","movie #2"]]}
{"result":[["4901","movie #1",],["2507","movie #2"],["2644","movie #3"]]}
```

I want to return in each iteration only the result of the **Id** of each index in

Comment: are expect results : `{"result": [["4901", "movie #1"]]}`; `{"result": [["2507", "movie #2"]]}`;`{"result": [["2644", "movie #3"]]}`; ???

Answer (score 0):

You create your json in the while loop. It's the reason of your result.
Try this :

```
<?php
$array_1 = array(4901,2507,2644);
$array_length = count($array_1);
$iterator=0;
while($iterator < $array_length)
{

$record_id = $array_1[$iterator];
$url = "https://example.com" . $record_id;
$curl = curl($url);
$json = fetch_value($curl, '<script type="application/ld+json">', '</script>');
$movie_id = fetch_value($curl, 'id="page_id" value="', '">');
$name = fetch_value($curl, '"name":"', '",');

 $movie_info[] = array(
                "0" => $movie_id,
                "1" => $name,
);
   
$iterator++;
}

$result = array("result" => $movie_info);
$data = json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$data = PHP_EOL . $data;
$myfile = file_put_contents('final.txt', $data.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```